# Create a unique random ID

Tags: php, random, unique-id

Since couple of days, i have a problem with my function who generate a random id.

Here is the function :

```
public static function generatePin($max)
{
        $key = "";
        $possibilities = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $possibilities .= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $possibilities .= "0123456789";
        $i = 0;
        while ($i <= $max) {
            $detail = Tools::substr($possibilities, mt_rand(0, Tools::strlen($possibilities)-1), 1);
            $key .= $detail;
            $i++;
        }
        return $key;
```

In my file, when i want to use this function, i used to do that (works fine since many months) :

```
    $this->my_secure_pin = Tools::encrypt(Class::generatePin(7));
```

Now, my variable "secure_pin" can't change.. I always have the same ID and it doesn't want to change as it used to do.. My random ID become a same ID for every request.. Grrrr

**Here an example :**

1/ I go on my page, my variable "secure_pin" is 622c7da19ec263b59f452b9fc5.

2/ I refresh my page, my variable "secure_pin" is always 622c7da19ec263b59f452b9fc5

3/ I leave my page and i come back to her, my variable "secure_pin" is always 622c7da19ec263b59f452b9fc5

4/ If i empty cache, my variable "secure_pin" is changing !..

=> So, when many persons come to my page, they have all the same "secure_pin"... :-(

I want (as couple days ago) a secure_pin for every persons who come on this page, a changing "secure_pin" if i refresh page or if i come back to her etc..

No changes, No updates, nothing.. Any idea ? :'(

Many thanks for your help !

**EDIT 1** : Here is the "encrypt" function :

```
public static function encrypt($passwd)
{
    return md5(pSQL(_COOKIE_KEY_.$passwd));
}
```

**EDIT 2** : Here is the "substr" function :

```
static function substr($str, $start, $length = false, $encoding = 'utf-8')
{
    if (is_array($str))
        return false;
    if (function_exists('mb_substr'))
        return mb_substr($str, (int)($start), ($length === false ? self::strlen($str) : (int)($length)), $encoding);
    return substr($str, $start, ($length === false ? self::strlen($str) : (int)($length)));
}
```

Comment: What is `$max`?

Comment: It's the string for my function generatePin()

Comment: Everything looks fine to me (https://3v4l.org/6rfJW). Generates a different "Pin" each call. The only thing that should cause that to generate the same pin all the time would be if you are seeding the RNG with the same value on each load. However, even that would mean that subsequent calls to the same function would generate different numbers.

Comment: Sorry, but why would the standard PHP functions be called using `Tools` though? If for a moment, `Tools` was removed, the code would work just fine.

Comment: Sorry i forgot something :) "Tools" allow to call Tools.php.. I edited my post for showing thhis "encrypt function"

Comment: @Shark34 Try to call `mt_srand` at the beginning of your code to reinitialize the seed of random number generator.

Comment: @user4035 In my function generatePin or before Tools::encrypt(Class::generatePin(7)); ?

Comment: Can you also post "Tools::substr"?

Comment: @JannesBotis Done ! Thank for your help.. ! I despair lol

Comment: @Shark34 before Tools::encrypt(Class::generatePin(7));

Comment: @user4035 I tried but not working :(

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Why it's always the same result if i close the page and i open it in a new tab ? I want a different random "Pin" at every connexion..

Comment: @Shark34 Let's check random number generation: at the beginning of the page call: `print mt_rand(0, 10);exit;`. When you refresh the page does it generate a new random number?

Comment: This is starting to get too broad for the SO format. Questions on SO need to have definite answers and while I'm sure there is one here, it isn't likely to be found without some discussion which is not what SO is here for. Further comments are likely going to start being regarding debugging your code which requires back and forth discussion. Perhaps you should try asking somewhere else that you could have a discussion.